# Automatically compile less css files in mac os x

Tags: css, automation, less

I have started using less CSS.

I have written a small bash script which calls the "lessc" command with my target file and then pipes it into my finished css file. It looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
lessc ~/Documents/Development/Projects/blog/static/css/global.less --watch > ~/Documents/Development/Projects/blog/static/css/styles.css -x
```

This -x flag compresses the CSS.

As you can see I have tried to use the --watch flag which from what I understood would mean it would automatically recompile the CSS every time you make a change to the less files. But this doesnt seem to work.

I realise I could use the "less app" that someone has written, but Im curious as to how to do this myself, as it's clearly possible.

Comment: Use Guard.
https://github.com/mloberg/guard-less (this fork contains an up-to-date gem dependency versions)

Answer (score 2):

Because less often uses @imports, it's an over-engineered solution to watch all the files involved. You can just use a simple loop to compile every so often, for example:

```
while true; do lessc bootstrap.less > bootstrap.css 2> /dev/null; sleep 5; done
```

If this is too simplistic, then you could try using the -nt test in Bash, which tests if a file's mtime is newer than the other, for example (supposing bootstrap.less contains an @import for custom.less):

```
while true
do
    if [ bootstrap.less -nt bootstrap.css ] || [ custom.less -nt bootstrap.css ]; then
        echo "Change detected, regenerating @ $(date)"
        lessc bootstrap.less > bootstrap.css
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```